# Измерение разниц в секундах между двумя значениями времени

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Нужно замерить время работы программы, используются объекты класса

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); 
auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count();
```

Источник [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1983296.html).